# How to make a new variable based on 30 other variables

Tags: variables, if-statement

I have 30 variables on family history of cancer i.e. breast cancer father, breast cancer mother, breast cancer sister etc. I would like to make a new variable and give it a value of "1" if in one of my columns there is a 1. 
Thus: 
I have 30 variables with answers 1 to 3; 1 is yes, 2 is no and, 3 is unknown if one of the 30 variables is given a 1 I would like my new variable to take on the value 1. 
Does someone know how I can do this?

Comment: Any language preference? Or just the algorithm?

Comment: are your 30 variables in an integer array?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list instead of separate 30 variables and then filter it out to create a new variable. This will make it more dynamic.

```
// This will be the cancer history for a single family
var cancerHistory = [];

// Add dummy data
cancerHistory.push('yes');
cancerHistory.push('no')
cancerHistory.push('unknown');
cancerHistory.push('no');

// Check if at least one of them is "yes"
var hasHistoryOfCancer = cancerHistory.indexOf('yes') > -1;

alert(hasHistoryOfCancer); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop. You did not mention the language so I am writing the code in Python which is easy to understand. If you want it in other language you can use the similar approach and apply it

```
import pandas as pd

new_var = []
df = pd.read_csv("DataFile.csv") # Convert data file to csv and put name it.
for i in range(len(df)):
    x = [df['column1'][i], df['column2'][i] ...., df['column30'][i]]
    if (1 in x): new_var.append(1)
    else: new_var.append(0)

df['new_var'] = new_var
df.to_csv('NewDataFile.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
```